# Different declarations of matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, attributes

I made the following's declaration:

Implementation 1:

```
int m[3][3];

m[0][0] = 1;
m[0][1] = 4;
m[0][2] = 5;
m[1][0] = 5;
m[1][1] = 7;
m[1][2] = 6;
m[2][0] = 5;
m[2][1] = 8;
m[2][2] = 8;
```

Implementation 2:

```
int m[3][3];

int m = { 
    {1,4,5},
    {5,7,8},
    {5,8,8},
};
```

Implementation 1 works just fine, but Implementation 2 results in a wrong output in my code (which is too long to put here) and I wanted to use 2 because is more compact. Why is the result in my output being different?

Comment: what's the output? [mcve] please. Note: implementation 2 doesn't work as is since it defines `m` twice. simplify work of people who'll try to answer. [mcve] output & expected output please

Comment: `int m = { .... }` doesn't work, `m` was declared as an integer...

Answer (score 1):

For me, the following code works perfectly:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int m[3][3] = { 
    {1,4,5},
    {5,7,8},
    {5,8,8},
};
    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<3; j++){
        printf("%d \n",m[i][j]);
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 
4 
5 
5 
7 
8 
5 
8 
8
```

Comment: If I declare int m[3][3]; how do I put values into the matrix afterwords?

Comment: @Pinteco: A need to reinitialize an array in that way rarely arises in practical code. If multiple sets of prepared data are needed in a program, it is usually better to define multiple arrays and use whichever one is needed at the moment rather than to copy all the data into one array. However, if one needs to copy a set of prepared values into an array, it can be done with `memcpy(m, (int [3][3]) { {1,4,5}, {5,7,8}, {5,8,8}, }, sizeof m);`.